# Adjusting checkboxes To Align Center

Tags: html, css

I want to adjust checkboxes in the middle of screen.

My html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="get" style="text-align: center">
<input  name="check1" type="checkbox">short text<br>
<input  name="check2" type="checkbox">medium-length text__________<br>
<input  name="check3" type="checkbox">long text________________________________<br>
<input name="Submit1" type="submit" value="submit"></form>
</body>
</html>
```

The checkboxes are on different positions because of different text length.
What's the best way to adjust them to a vertical line roughly to the position of the checkbox of the longest text ("check3")?

I'm sorry for this probably simple question.

Comment: If you can set a width on the form you could do: `<form method="get" style="margin: 0 auto; width: 500px;">` and replace the `500px` with the appropriate width. Note: You should remove the `text-align` property.

Answer (score 2):

You can change it to this which I believe will get you what you want:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="get" style="text-align: center;">
        <div style="display: inline-block; text-align: left;">
            <input  name="check1" type="checkbox">short text<br>
            <input  name="check2" type="checkbox">medium-length text__________<br>
            <input  name="check3" type="checkbox">long text________________________________
        </div>
        <br>
        <input name="Submit1" type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This way you don't need to know the width of your text beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

You can go with something as simple as setting a `width` to your form and then setting `margin: 0 auto` like so:

### HTML

```
<form method="get">
    <input  name="check1" type="checkbox" />short text<br>
    <input  name="check2" type="checkbox" />medium-length text__________<br>
    <input  name="check3" type="checkbox" />long text________________________________<br>
    <input name="Submit1" type="submit" value="submit" />
 </form>
```

### CSS

```
form { display: block; margin: 0 auto; width: 400px; }
```

## jsFiddle

### !OR!

If you don't want to set the width, you can set the `display` of the `form` to `table` and get the same result, but with an `auto` width:

**HTML** -> the same

### CSS

```
form { display: table; margin: 0 auto; }
```

## jsFiddle

---

**!OR!**

---

If you want it ***fully*** centered, horizontal and vertical, you can use a variation of the following:

### HTML

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <form method="get">
                    <input  name="check1" type="checkbox" />short text<br />
                    <input  name="check2" type="checkbox" />medium-length text__________<br />
                    <input  name="check3" type="checkbox" />long text________________________________<br />
                    <input name="Submit1" type="submit" value="submit" />
                 </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

### CSS

```
html, body { margin: 0; height: 100%; width: 100%; }
table { height: 100%; margin: 0 auto; }
td { vertical-align: middle; }
```

### jsFiddle

Answer (score 0):

Use div tag  and then u can use margin attribute and remove 
    **style="text-align: center**" 
form form tag

```
#checkbox {
float:left
margin-left:70px;
}


<div id="checkbox">
<form method="get" >
<input  name="check1" type="checkbox">short text<br>
<input  name="check2" type="checkbox">medium-length text__________<br>
<input  name="check3" type="checkbox">long text________________________________<br>
<input name="Submit1" type="submit" value="submit"></form>
   </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/48fwg/